# Why do MockMvc tests suggest injecting WebApplicationContext @BeforeEach test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

So the reference documentation suggests

```java
    @BeforeEach
    void setup( WebApplicationContext wac) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( wac )
            .apply( SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity() )
            .alwaysDo( print() )
            .build();
    }
```

why not do it as constructor injection instead? (I haven't tried this, I'm just assuming it doesn't immediately blow up)

```java
    @Autowired
    MyControllerTest(
        @NonNull WebApplicatonContext wac
    ) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( wac )
            .apply( SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity() )
            .alwaysDo( print() )
            .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you choose constructor injection, method injection, or field injection is a matter of taste when using JUnit Jupiter with the `SpringExtension`.

The example in the reference manual simply shows one way to do it using a `@BeforeEach` method since many people are familiar with performing test setup within a "before" method.

You can also set up your `MockMvc` instance within the test class constructor, and you can make your `mockMvc` field `final` if you like.

In [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/ee41ebc1ab77f5e0b8d956b4891e219dd6cfecf6), I updated a test class in Spring's own test suite to demonstrate some of these techniques in practice.

Please note that the test class constructor does not need to be annotated with `@Autowired` if it accepts a single argument that is compatible with `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if maybe it was getting recreated each test, for a reason.

Comment: So, did I answer your question then?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forget about these sometimes